# How to iterate string in cmd for loop?

Tags: windows, string, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to iterate a string in batch script:

```
set var="1 2 3"

for /F %%i in (%var%) do (  
  echo %%i
)
```

and getting this output:

```
C:\>batch.bat


C:\>set var="1 2 3"

C:\>for /F %i in ("1 2 3") do (echo %i )

C:\>(echo 1 )
1
```

I expect that all 3 numbers will be printed:

```
1
2
3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because FOR/F splits a each line into multiple tokens, but you need to define how many tokens you want to process.

```
set var="1 2 3"

for /F "tokens=1-3" %%i in (%var%) do (  
  echo %%i
  echo %%j
  echo %%k
)
```

**EDIT:** Other solutions

Like the answer of Ed harper:
You could also use a normal FOR-loop, with the limitation that it will also try to serach for files on the disk, and it have problems with `*` and `?`.

```
set var=1 2 3

for %%i in (%var%) do  (
    echo %%i
)
```

Or you use **linefeed technic** with the FOR/F loop, replacing your delim-character with a linefeed.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set "var=1 2 3 4 5"
set "var=%var: =!LF!%"
for /F %%i in ("!var!") do (  
  echo %%i
)
```

This works as the FOR/F sees five lines splitted by a linefeed instead of only one line.

Comment: This is the most close to what I want. The only disadvantage is that I don't know in advance the number of tokens - it is user input. I guess it can be fixed by choosing some value equals to maximum tokens list size such as `"tokens=1-10"`.

Comment: @ks1322 You could also use the linefeed technic

Answer (score 5):

Try `FOR` in place of `FOR /F`. Also, quoting the value when setting `var` is unnecessary:

```
set var=1 2 3

for %%i in (%var%) do  (
echo %%i
)
```

Comment: @Ed, I want to iterate string, delimited by whitespaces, so I guess quoting is necessary

Comment: @Alvin, Joey - did you try my example? (Although you're right, /D is unnecessary)

Comment: @ks1322 - quoting isn't necessary in batch scripts - space is the default delimiter (hence why you have to quote file system paths containing spaces)

Answer (score 2):

Because `FOR /F` loops every line of a text file, and when used with a string (`""` quoted) it only do things on that line. It *does* delimit by whitespace, but that is to be used with the option `tokens`.

You should use `FOR`

```
set var=1 2 3

for %%i in (%var) do (
  echo %%i
)
```

If you want to loop numbers, use the following:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (
  echo %%i
)
```