# Tokenize strings in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, tokenize, stringtokenizer, split

Suppose I have a file, and I don't know how many words there are in it. I would like to go through this file and echo every word, one at a time. Is there a way to do that? The delim is space and I don't know how many words I will be going through because the file content may change.

For example, if the file contains:

```
"Hello world
I hope winter should be over soon"
```

Then I would like the output to be:

```
"Hello
world
I
hope
winter
should
be
over
soon"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in batch. I picked this up here awhile back but I don't remember who wrote it. Probably Jeb or dbenham. It looks like their code ;)

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:: Define LF to contain a newline character
set LF=^


:: Above 2 blank lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE
for /f "eol= tokens=*" %%A in (hw.txt) do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%L in ("!LF!") do (
    for /f "eol= " %%W in ("!ln: =%%~L!") do echo %%W
  )
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of disabledelayedexpansion please?

Comment: @Slav DisableDelayedExpansion is necessary to avoid problems with exclamation marks in the line `set "ln=%%A"`, but then you need to Enable it, to be able to use the content in `ln` in a safe way

Comment: @Matt I suppose it's from dbenham, as the comments haven't my style :-)

Comment: @Matt I am genuinely interested to understand how this works. So far I just don't get `for %%L in ("!LF!") do (stuff)`. I am reading this as `for element %%L in ("carret/newline")`... what?? How can there be elements in a single `^`

Comment: @Slav This explains the linefeed trick [SO:How to iterate string in cmd for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11154068/463115)

Comment: @jeb Thank you for the link. That part (about substituting space with newline and using `for /f` to iterate through it) I get. What is throwing me off is `for %%L in ("!LF!") do (stuff)`. Is that a typo? Should that be `!ln!` in parenthesis? I don't understand how you can iterate through `!LF!` which **only** contains a single `^`

Comment: @Slav You should open a new question... But here the first `FOR %%L("!LF!")` is used to get the linefeed into `%%~L`, so it's possible to replace all spaces with the linefeed in the next FOR with `!ln: =%%~L!`

Answer (score 1):

The following will work, **unless** there are double quotes in the text.txt file. Are you sure you are going to have double quotes in your text file? If you don't care about the double quotes, this can be further tuned to strip out the quotes before splitting it

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Read file text.txt line by line
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%X IN (text.txt) DO (
    CALL :SPLIT %%X
)
EXIT /B 0

:SPLIT
:: Verify parameter is not blank, else quit
IF ["%*"]==[""] EXIT /B 0
:: Extract first token, recursively :SPLIT the remainder
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%A IN ("%*") DO (
    ECHO %%A
    CALL :SPLIT %%B
)
```

The first `FOR` loop will read the text.txt file, line by line.

The `:SPLIT` recursive function will take a line, and split it by delimiter of space until there is nothing left in the line.

Comment: It works ... more or less..., but to use CALL with a parameter by value is in batch always problematic, it can't handle any special chars like `<>&|` and carets will be removed

Comment: @jeb, how would you pass value to a function in batch then?

Comment: By reference to a variable, first set the value to a variable `set "var=%%A"` and `CALL :SPLIT var` and access in the function via `set "param=!%1!"`

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.txt"|repl " " "\r\n" x
```